# Are giant shell scripts ideal for the governance of a git repository using pgp keys?

Tags: python, git, encryption, blockchain, pgp

The link below has the repository for a giant shell script that is supposed to:
- Issue digital value tokens
- Create, sign, and enforce contracts
- Participate in projects in a democratic, decentralized manner

https://github.com/GitGuild/gitguild/blob/isysd/gitguild

Is it safe to run this giant script? Is it a best practice?

It seems the script is not interacting well with the user's git configuration.  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: This question is better suited to [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) as it's a security question rather than a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any doubt regarding the execution of a code from a remote origin (like this GitHub repo), the best practice is to mount a virtual machine (like VirtualBox or VMWare)

Within that VM (isolated from your host), you can try any script you want with less risk.